# Battery charging and amperage for Li-Ion

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

Simple question:
Is low amperage good for battery? Is it decrease wear level?
Ex: we have battery with 2A recommended. Will it be better to charge it with 1A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that reduces temperature rise <10 deg C results in reduced aging rates but longer charge times. So it is a tradeoff between life expectancy and Amps per Amp hour capacity.  e.g. using a C/10 battery in C/5 mode improves life expectancy by x% (ref needed) if that reduces temp rise.

### I^2*ESR=Pd then Pd*Rja = T_rise

- The charge or discharge current squared times the internal Effective Series Resistance , ESR = Power dissipated, Pd. Then the thermal resistance from internal cell junction to ambient, Rja, determines the temperature rise of the cell chemistry.
- [Arrhenius Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation) says *"for every approx 10 deg C rise, reaction rate doubles"* which means life expectancy is reduced by 50% ( for the duty cycle at that temperature)

Comment: so the question becomes, how much is waiting worth to you if you have spares? to get a little more charge cycles out of your battery.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, yes. That mostly depends on the particular battery chemistry, be sure to consult its datasheet.
For NiMH it's a different matter, since the good chargers there use delta-V overcharging detection, which gets more unreliable if the charging current is lowered.